# How to include properly Javascript files into twig template Symfony3.4

Tags: javascript, twig, symfony-3.4

I'm using `jms/twig-js` library and want to import twig as js just like they show in [the usage page](http://jmsyst.com/libs/twig.js/master/usage) Here is my example:

agent_company.html.twig

```
{% twig_js name="agent_company" %}
         some code ...
```

agents_create.html.twig

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="twig.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="agent_company.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  Twig.render(agent_company);
</script>
```

At the end I got [image]

I wanna mentioned that before I use `JMSTwigJsBundle` for Symfony2 and this code works fine:

```
{% javascripts "@PartnersManagerBundle/Resources/views/Default/agent_company.html.twig" filter="twig_js" %}
  <script language="javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

So, I think my problem is with wrong pointing to the files. I accept any suggestions. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The library `forknetwork/twig-js-bundle` works for all versions. 
Version 2.1.0 work with Symfony 3 and v4.0.0 with Symfony 4. So I use my old code and just update the library version.